# Iterative Hanoi tower algorithm slower than the recursive one

Tags: c, performance, recursion

I made an iterative algorithm to solve the Hanoi tower problem without using an explicit stack data structure, but just using a single variable as a stack.

The idea was that I can use a single 64 bit variable and use each bit to record the "status" of the steps, and I would use it as a stack. I also use another variable as some sort of stack pointer, so it would effectively "point" to witch bit of the stack variable is at.

If the bit is 0, it means that it still has to move the disks away to take the lower one.
If the bit is 1 instead, it has finished and returns to the previous step of the stack

I also use another variable to tell the "direction" of the call stack.

I was doing some tests with my solution and I found out that it is slower than the recursive one.

This is the code for my iterative solution:

```
unsigned long long int steps = 0; // Keep track of how many movements we made.

void hanoi_iterative(int disks, int start, int target, int temp) {
    unsigned long long int stack = 0; // 64 position stack, with every bit as a cell.

    int is_returning = 0; // Indicates the current "direction" of the call stack.
    int stack_pos = disks; // Stack pointer.

    while (stack_pos <= disks) {
        if (stack_pos == 1) {
            // printf("%d -> %d\n", start, target); // Print the movement.
            steps++;

            stack_pos++;
            is_returning = 1;
            continue;
        }

        // Check the current bit on the stack.
        if (!(stack & 1llu<<stack_pos)) {
            if (!is_returning) {
                // Swapping target and temp.
                target ^= temp;
                temp ^= target;
                target ^= temp;

                stack_pos--;

                // Set the bit of the next step as 0.
                stack &= ~(1llu<<stack_pos);
                // is_returning = 0; // Redundant, look at the if.
                continue;
            }
            
            // Swapping target and temp.
            target ^= temp;
            temp ^= target;
            target ^= temp;

            // printf("%d -> %d\n", start, target); // Print the movement
            steps++;

            // Change the actual bit to 1, we did the first part.
            stack |= 1llu<<stack_pos;

            // Swapping start and temp.
            start ^= temp;
            temp ^= start;
            start ^= temp;
            
            stack_pos--;

            // Set the bit of the next step as 0.
            stack &= ~(1llu<<stack_pos);
            is_returning = 0;
            continue;
        }
        
        // Swapping start and temp.
        start ^= temp;
        temp ^= start;
        start ^= temp;

        stack_pos++;
        // is_returning = 1; // Redundant, it should already be 1.
    }
}
```

This is the recursive one:

```
unsigned long long int steps = 0; // Keep track of how many movements we made.

void hanoi_recursive(int disks, int start, int target, int temp) {
    if (disks == 1) {
        // printf("%d -> %d\n", start, target); // Print the movement.
        steps++;
        return;
    }

    hanoi_recursive(disks - 1, start, temp, target);
    // printf("%d -> %d\n", start, target);
    steps++;
    hanoi_recursive(disks - 1, temp, target, start);
}
```

I tried as many optimizations that I know, but I don't know if it is normal that the iterative solution is slower than the recursive one.

In general, on my machine, I see that the recursive solution is twice as fast than the iterative one.

I wanted to try to do some profiling, but I don't have much experience on how to do it so I wanted to know if there are more obvious reasons of why my iterative implementation is slower.

Edit:
My question is if there are iterative C programs for the Hanoi tower problem that are faster than the recursive one, since it is told than iteratation is generally faster than recursion.

I tried some solutions on the internet but they were all slower, so I made an implementation that is as fast as I can make, using bit manipulation and a single variable as a memory, but it seems that the recursion overhead is still smaller than the operation overhead that my solution does.

Comment: Well your iterative function does quite a lot more than the recursive solution. So it's no wonder it takes longer time.

Comment: Yeah, I think that would make sense. I tried other implementations of this problem using iteration but they performed very similar to my solution. Since it is usually told that iteration is faster than recursion I wanted to know if it should be the case also for this problem.

Comment: what exactly is your question? ..  please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Edited, now it should be clearer.